# How to create Ember Service that fetches data from Apollo GraphQL Server

Tags: ember.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I successfully fetched data from Apollo GraphQL Server in Amber route using [ember-apollo-client](https://github.com/ember-graphql/ember-apollo-client). I tried the same approach to have a service fetching data but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.apollo.query is not a function` from `app/services/nav-categories.js`.

## Minimal Working Example

Start a new app using

```
$ ember new super-rentals --lang en
$ ember generate service nav-categories
```

Configure Apollo end point in `config/environment.js`:

```
module.exports = function (environment) {
  const ENV = {
    ...

    apollo: {
      apiURL: 'http://localhost:4000',
    }
  };
```

`app/gql/queries/allCategories.graphql`:

```
query AllCategories {
  categories {
    name
  }
}
```

`app/services/nav-categories.js`:

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { queryManager } from "ember-apollo-client";
import allCategories from "super-rentals/gql/queries/allCategories.graphql";

export default class NavCategoriesService extends Service {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.apollo = queryManager();
    this.categories = this.apollo.query({ query: allCategories });
  }
}
```

`app/components/my-header.js`:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { service } from '@ember/service';

export default class CartContentsComponent extends Component {
  // Will load the service defined in: app/services/nav-categories.js
  @service navCategories;
}
```

`app/components/my-header.hbs`:

```
<ul>
{{#each this.navCategories.categories as |category|}}
  <li>{{category.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

`app/templates/application.hbs`:

```
<MyHeader></MyHeader>
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: I think you may want https://glimmer-apollo.com/docs/fetching/queries instead, because you can use `gql` -- it also has much more modern examples

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/ember-graphql/ember-apollo-client#query-manager-api), `query` does not return an array (as it looks like you're expecting, based on usage).

`query` returns a promise.

> It returns a promise that resolves with the raw POJO data that the query returns.

So this means you can't synchronously set a `categories` field to your list of `categories`.

### Set a property after .then

Keeping in mind that you need to handle early-destruction protection yourself,
so that tests are stable

```js
import { isDestroying, isDestroyed } from '@ember/destroyable';

export default class NavCategoriesService extends Service {
  @tracked categories = [];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.apollo = queryManager();
    this.apollo.query({ query: allCategories })
      .then(pojoData => {
        // we can't set properties on `this` if `this` is destroyed
        if (isDestroying(this) || isDestroyed(this)) return;
    
        this.categories = pojoData.whatever.results;
      });

  }
}
```

### Use resource utilities to help manage the state involved with promises

Promises have error, loading, etc states, so it's good to correctly handle all those.
there are utilities

```js
import { trackedFunction } from 'ember-resources/util/function';
import { use, resourceFactory } from 'ember-resources';

function Categories() {
  return trackedFunction(async () => {
    let apollo = queryManager();

    return apollo.query({ query: allCategories });
  });
})

export default class NavCategoriesService extends Service {
  @use categoriesRequest = Categories();

  get isLoading() {
    return this.categoriesRequest.isLoading;
  }

  get categories() {
    return this.categoriesRequset.value ?? [];
  }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-resources/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still get the same error: `TypeError: this.apollo.query is not a function` when I try the first snippet. And I get a similar error when I try the second snippet: `TypeError: this.categoriesRequset is undefined`.

Comment: which approach did you do, and did you install the needed dependencies if you went with the second one?